# simulating a trading card game in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, playing-cards

More specifically, I'm trying to simulate the Pokemon TCG, if that helps.

Currently, I have a handle on the basic elements of the game, like drawing cards and shuffling. However, I am lost on how to implement the functionalities unique to certain cards.

To simplify things, I have a deck class and a card class. The card class includes variables like a card's name and type, and it gets their values by extracting them from a database. But say, if I'm trying to create a Base Set Charizard, how would I store and call his poke-power (read:ability), as it has effects beyond the normal rules of the game and needs its own code.

Would it be efficient (or is it even possible) to store the code for the ability into a database and call it when needed? If not, what are the best alternatives to attack this situation?

Comment: You should probably include more information on the game, like what sorts of cards there are and how they interact, if you want people that are not familiar with it be able to help. You could also look into posting this question on [the gamedev stackexchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try that. I didn't want to include game-specific information, because it was a general problem, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would store the code in a database, or even against the card. I think you need to separate out the code that **does** the abilities, and the **defining** of the ability for each card.

You probably need to abstract out each effect, and an ability/poke-power will be a collection of different "effect" with different values. This could get pretty complicated, and is not a simple task. There will be abilities that share the same effects, so abstracting these out will make sure you don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't store AS3 code in a database, but storing properties of the cards in a database would be a good idea. Then when creating the cards have a factory class that reads these properties and instantiates objects using the data.